# How to replace the whole child element with another one?

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to replace the inner div of the parent element  with another element. And I want to to do this with javascript

```
<fieldset>
    div class="icheckbox_minimal" style="position: relative;">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Do you use jQuery?

Comment: @AndréReichelt nope simple Javascript

Comment: Ill give you a hint, so you can complete it yourself, document.getElementsByTagName('fieldset')[0].firstElementChild

Comment: `replaceWith()` does exactly this (assuming you're okay without Internet Explorer compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith

Comment: @Gavin yeah maybe it will do the thing

Comment: If you need IE use replaceChild https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
 document.getElementsByTagName('fieldset')[0].firstElementChild.outerHTML = 'your html here'
```